# function setDataSource() in the AppModel

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I use this syntax in the AppModel

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null)
{           
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->setDataSource('new_db');
}
```

The problem is that when this function is called,

```
Database Error

Error: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: 
missing FROM-clause entry for table "Aco" LINE 1: ...AND "Permission"."aco_id" IN (3, 2, 1) ORDER BY "Aco"."lft... ^
```

I think this error appears due to the fact that the component ACL is linked to a database which is the default.

Comment: what is your question? how to avoid that error? either put an acl definition in the new db or don't check for permissions when you change db.

Comment: yes, that's how to avoid this error, it occurs when a change in the database, in the AppModel